# JavaScript, how to grab the selected value from one list and simultaneously change in another list

Tags: javascript

I have 2 select lists. There is a check box that when it is clicked it needs to feed the selected value selected into the other list.

I am up to the stage where I have managed to alert back the selected value in the first select list, my question is how to get the value in the second select list when the checkbox is clicked:

Please check code below of how far I have got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function displayResult() {
      if(document.form1.billingtoo.checked == true) {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
        alert(y[x].text);
      }
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="form1">
    Select your favorite fruit:
        <select id="mySelect">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option>Pineapple</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
        </select>

        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo" onclick="displayResult()">

        <br>

    Select your favorite fruit 2:
        <select id="mySelect2">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Orange</option>
            <option>Pineapple</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
        </select>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use Javascript, but feel free to share using jQuery.

Comment: I'm reading this over and over and I don't understand this: "it needs to feed the selected value selected into the other list" If the user selects Orange from mySelect and then checks the checkbox, what needs to happen with mySelect2??? It seems from your question that the second Select already has the same values as the first one. Could you clarify??????

Comment: It needs to simultaneously change, if I select Orange in mySelect, once I tick the checkbox it needs to change to Orange in the mySelect2 list. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then $('#mySelect2').val($('#mySelect').val()); is the jquery version.

Comment: Thanks mate, all sorted.

Comment: I made an update to the jsfiddle Gabe did so that you can see the one-liner jquery version: http://jsfiddle.net/Skvst/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the selected index of the other select element.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Skvst/)

```
if(document.form1.billingtoo.checked == true) {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;
        // Set selected index for mySelect2
        document.getElementById("mySelect2").selectedIndex = x;
}
```

You could `get` and `set` the `value` `property` of the `object`, if you're worried about the order of options being different.

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cmb5n/)

```
if(document.form1.billingtoo.checked == true) {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options;

        document.getElementById("mySelect2").value = x;       
}
```

Comment: Upvoted you for the jsfiddle. Only issue with your approach is that the items need to be in the same order; but that's for the OP's to think about. The jquery approach I suggested removes this limitation.